# Is it possible to bind ⌘← and ⌘→ on Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

I'd like to bind `⌘←` and `⌘→` on Terminal.app to going to the start and end of the line respectively so it behaves like any (almost) other program in Mac OS X. Is it possible?

I went to Preferences and to configure key bindings and the only modifier keys are control, option, none and shift.

Comment: Yes, fideli, apparently it's impossible. If you want to add a question stating that it is impossible, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be possible because ⌘← and ⌘→ change focus between multiple Terminal windows, a functionality that appears to be built-in. I checked out the Secrets Preference Pane for Terminal and there doesn't seem to be anything there.

Having said that, a similar move that's convenient on MacBook or MacBook Pro keyboards is ⇧fn← and ⇧fn→, which correspond to ⇧↖ and ⇧↘.

Comment: ⇧⌃← and ⇧⌃→ seem to move only one character with the default config. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was doing ⇧fn← and ⇧fn→ on my MacBook, which correspond to ⇧↖ and ⇧↘. I'll edit my response, although I suppose it's only somewhat convenient on the MacBook or MacBook Pro keyboard, and not on the regular Apple keyboard.

Comment: You can override the default shortcuts using the OSX Keyboard & Mouse preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you want, but I've found that the emacs ^A and ^E seem to work in a lot of mac applications, so it might be easier to rewire your habits to use these keys instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually psueodo bound this by using controllermate to emulate ⇧↖ and ⇧↘ on using ⌘← and ⌘→, and attaching it to terminal as the focussed application. works like a dream.